# JavaScript, oninput change innerHTML of option tag

Tags: javascript, html-select

i need to change the innerHTML text of a option tag, based on the input of an input form. I did it like this but as soon as i write "1" it gets locked up and i cannot write anything else there. It does change the text but it doesn't allow you to write anything else, or change from 1 to the value of 2 for example.

```
function change_let_rok()
{
    if (document.kombpred.nn.value = "1") {
        document.kombpred.obdobi.options[0].innerHTML = "Rok";
    }
        else {
            document.kombpred.obdobi.options[0].innerHTML = "Let";
    }
}
```

The html code is:

```
<form name="kombpred">
<input style ="display:inline;" name=nn type=text size=15 class='innerc resform' oninput="change_let_rok()"> 
    <select name="obdobi" style="display:inline;">
    <option value="let">Let</option>
    <option value="mesice">Mesice</option>
    <option value="ctvrtlety">Ctvrtlety</option>
    <option value="pulroky">Pulroky</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, it would be a little more proper to use `.text` instead of `.innerHTML` for `option` elements.

Comment: And is it needed the else statement, in order to return the values to the normal ones if the number is not 1????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have 1 equals sign in your if statement. Should be '=='.
Also your values for the options should probably be 1,2,3,and 4 respectively.

Comment: is it needed the else statement, in order to return the values to the normal ones if the number is not 1????

Comment: You could put one if statement for each option. In the if for that option add statements to change the other options to their defaults.